# Energy released due to electrons transition

Tags: atomic-physics, photon-emission

I came across this question in one of my physics books:
Choose the correct answer:

According to Bohr's model of the Hydrogen atom, the transition of an electron from n=2 to n=1 leads to release of energy, its magnitude equals.....

( 3hc/4λ - hc/4λ - hc/2λ )

I can't really understand which λ is being referenced here. Shouldn't the correct answer just be: hc/λ ?

Thanks!

Comment: the magnitude equals zero?!

Comment: Zero? The energy released should have some value from the relation: E=-13.6/n^2 ev. The model answer states 3hc/4λ as the correct answer though.

Comment: Which book? Which page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE :

What $\lambda$ means must be stated somewhere in the book. My guess is that it is the shortest wavelength emitted, corresponding to the capture of a free electron by the $H^+$ ion.  So $\frac{hc}{\lambda}$ equals the Rydberg constant $R_H$.

The emitted energy is therefore
$E_n - E_m = (\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{m^2})R_H = (\frac{1}{1^2} - \frac{1}{2^2})R_H = \frac34 \frac{hc}{\lambda}$.

ORIGINAL ANSWER :

What exactly is the question in your book? The statement beginning "According to Bohr's Model..." does not seem to be correct because ( 3hc/4λ - hc/4λ - hc/2λ ) = 0, regardless of the value of λ.  It is not possible to comment on what the book says unless you quote exactly what is printed in it.

Yes, the answer should be an energy in the range o to 13.6eV.

Comment: This is the exact word-to-word quote from the book

Comment: You wrote that the book contains this question, but your "quote" is not a question.  We also need some surrounding details to understand the context of the quote.

Comment: The book has supplementary exams at its end, this question is MCQ. Thanks!

Comment: Ah so ( 3hc/4λ - hc/4λ - hc/2λ ) are the 3 options and not the single answer?  You are really not helping yourself by being so reluctant to provide information to help us understand your question.

Comment: I thought it was clear, excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it means
 $$\lambda = h/p = \frac {h}{mv}$$ 
where
 $$v = \frac{e}{\sqrt{4\pi\epsilon_0mr}}$$
$r$ is the 'distance' of electron from the center, and thus
$$\lambda =\frac{h}{e}\sqrt{\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0r_n}{m}}$$
also,
$$n\lambda = 2\pi r_n$$
$$r_n = \frac{n^2h^2\epsilon_0}{\pi me^2} = n^2a_0$$
where $a_0 = r_1 = 5.92 \times10^{-11}m$

Just try it if it works... I took it from my book..

It also has
$$E_n = -\frac{e^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0r_n}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That doesn't help much with this question though.

Comment: $hc/\lambda$ I believe, is the energy for light traveling in vacuum. the energy difference for each state of the electron is different, and perhaps, it did not mean the $\lambda$ of the light emmited, but the $\lambda$ of the electron in orbit.

Comment: I mean the energy difference for each state of the electron is the same energy of the emitted.. but perhaps it did not mean the same $\lambda$